# Kerio VPN Client Connect but not work in 21.04

Tags: networking, vpn, 21.04

In Ubuntu 21.04 latest version of the Kerio VPN client (kerio-control-vpnclient-9.3.6-5738-linux-amd64.deb) is connected but not work and even the gateway of VPN not reach. I think some network changes affect Kerio VPN networking.

Comment: I have same issue in Kubuntu 21.04 (clean install). I found more detail and "workaround" there : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248506 But, if anybody know how to "repair" this issue, will be welcome :) Lukas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we can add

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "cat /var/log/kerio-kvc/debug.log | grep MAC | tail -1 | tr - : |rev|cut -d' '  -f 1|rev| xargs -I {} ip link set kvnet addr {}"
```

to `/lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service` as a workaround.

Comment: You might want to add that the above line should be added to service section for newbie like me. I had the same problem after upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04 and above solution works for me after adding it to service section inside service file.

Answer (score 3):

Using Lucas comment I somehow found a workaround. First open `/var/log/kerio-kvc/debug.log` file in an editor and search for `mac`. You will see something like this:

```
[02/Jul/2021 23:22:51] {vpnCore} VPN driver opened, version = 2.1, ifIndex = 22 (0x16), MAC xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

You might find several matches but use the last one. Convert `xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx` to `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`. Set `kvnet` interface mac manually:

```
sudo ip link set kvnet addr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on the suggestion above, I created this alias as workaround:

```
alias vpn='sudo service kerio-kvc restart && cat /var/log/kerio-kvc/debug.log | grep MAC | tail -1 | tr - : > grep.txt ; sudo ip link set kvnet addr `N=17; grep -o ".\{$N\}$" <grep.txt` &&   /usr/bin/google-chrome '\''http://[KERIO_SERVER]:4080//nonauth/totpVerify.cs'\'' &'
```

I am no expert in bash scripting; surely there is a way of doing this without writing it to a file.
However, this is fully automated.

Comment: I use this alias: `alias keriovpn="sudo service kerio-kvc restart && cat /var/log/kerio-kvc/debug.log | grep MAC | tail -1 | tr - : |rev|cut -d' '  -f 1|rev| xargs -I {} sudo ip link set kvnet addr {}"`